# Translation Using Dictionaries (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Alright so my teacher gave me the assignment below, and we have only been working with dictionaries for about a day:

1) Create a dictionary to translate a sentence from one language to another (such as Spanish to English).
2) The program should then write a sentence in the first language, then in the second language.

So far, my code is this:

```
def userinput():
    inputsentence = input("What sentence would you like to translate?(Hint! Make the sentence I speak _ more than my friends")
    spanoreng = input("Is this sentence Spanish or English?(Please enter span or eng")
    return(inputsentence,spanoreng)

def spantoeng(spantoengtras,inputsentence):
    inputsentence.lower()
    inputsentence.split()
    print(inputsentence)
def engtospan(engtospantrans,inputsentence):
    inputsentence.lower()
    inputsentence.split()
    print(inputsentence)
def main():
    spantoengtrans = {'yo' : 'I', 'hablo' : 'speak', 'espanol' : 'spanish', 'ingles' : 'english', 'mas' : 'more', 'de' : 'than','mis' : 'my', 'amigos' : 'friends'}
    engtospantrans = {'I' : 'yo', 'speak' : 'hablo', 'spanish' : 'espanol', 'english' : 'ingles', 'more' : 'mas', 'than' : 'de','my' : 'mis', 'friends' : 'amigos'}
    (inputsentence,spanoreng) = userinput()
    if spanoreng == 'span':
        spantoeng(spantoengtrans,inputsentence)
    elif spanoreng == 'eng':
        engtospan(engtospantrans,inputsentence)
    else:
        print("please type span or eng")
        (inputsentence,spanoreng) = userinput()


main()
```

All I'm having trouble with is changing the list using the dictionary. Also, my .lower() seems to not be doing anything. help?

EDIT: realized my mistake. thanks.

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python. The `lower()` method returns a new string that you have to assign to another variable or reassign back to `inputsentence`. The same applies for `split()`

Comment: You want to use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Answer (score 4):

I don't see **any** list -- I only see strings, which are immutable, and no use of the dictionary.

So the core function could be:

```
def translate(sentence, transdict):
    words = sentence.split()
    trans = [transdict.get(w.lower(),w) for w in words]
    print(' '.join(trans))
```

`split` makes the sentence into a list of whitespace-separated words; then the list comprehension makes it into a list of translated words (leaving words alone if they're not in the dictionary); finally we join the latter list back into a space-separated sentence.

Of course this leaves a lot to be desired, but it's hard to do better without regular expressions -- and if you've been using dictionaries for just a day regular expressions may be well beyond your studies so far. In case they're not:

```
import re

def maketrans(somedict):
    def trans(mo):
        word = mo.group()
        return somedict.get(word.lower(), word)
    return trans
```

and then

```
translated = re.sub(r'\w+', maketrans(right_dict), sentence)
print (translated)
```

will preserve punctuation and spacing.  But what between RE's and higher order functions, I suspect you'd better ignore this one until later in your Python studies:-).

Answer (score 0):

To start, you only need one `translate` function. The goal of this function should be to take some sentence and some dictionary, and output a sentence in the other language. To do that, I'd do something like this:

```
def translate(trans,inputsentence):
    inputsentence.lower()
    words = inputsentence.split(' ')
    new_sentence = [trans[w] for w in words]
    print(' '.join(new_sentence))
```

Next, for you input functions, you need to be calling `raw_input()` not `input()`. This will clean up the syntax errors.

```
def userinput():
    inputsentence = raw_input("What sentence would you like to translate?(Hint! ... > ")
    spanoreng = raw_input("Is this sentence Spanish or English? > ")
    return(inputsentence,spanoreng)
```

And that should pretty much do it, if you rename function calls inside `main()` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your primary question, but the reason that your lower() calls are not working is because you are calling `inputsentence.lower()` without assigning the returned value to a variable, so all it does is return the string in lowercase, but nothing is pointing to it. The original string remains the same. The same thing happens when you do `inputsentence.split()`, the list is created and returned, but it goes nowhere. Ultimately when you `return inputsentence` you are returning the exact same value you gave it, making lower() and split() do nothing.

If you want to replace the value of the variable `inputsentence` each time you use a string method you should do

```
inputsentence = inputsentence.lower().split()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign variables to the outputs of `.lower()` and then apply `.split()` to that variable. The output of *that* (saved as a variable) is what you want to return (or print in your current code).